# Trying to work with AJAX & PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I haven't worked with `AJAX` much but what I've been attempting to do is have a form where a user enters data, click submit and instead of refreshing the page for the result, a `modal window` opens with the result. My understanding is that I need to use `AJAX` for this to work.

The following is my code thus far. Please note that I am only trying to get the `AJAX` call to work first, I will worry about a modal window later.

At the moment, all that is achieved when hitting the submit button is the page performs the form action and goes to `testauthcall.php` where my result is `echo'd` on a blank page (I thought `return false;` was supposed to kill the page load?).

**HTML** File: testauth.php

```
<form id="myForm" action="testauthcall.php" method="post"> 
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" /> 
    Password: <input type="text" name="pass" />
    <input type="submit" value="Test Authentication" /> 
</form>
```

**Javascript** File: testauth.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var frm = $('#myForm');
frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            alert('ok');
        }
    });
    return false;
});

<script>
```

**PHP** File: testauthcall.php

```
require_once('variables/radius.class.php');

    if ((isset($_POST['user'])) && ('' != trim($_POST['user'])))
    {
        $radius = new Radius('xxx.xxx.xxx.xx', 'xxxxxxxxxx');

        if ($radius->AccessRequest($_POST['user'], $_POST['pass']))
        {
            $authresult = "<strong>Authentication accepted.</strong>";
            echo $authresult;
        }
        else
        {
            $authresult = "<strong>Authentication rejected.</strong>";
            echo $authresult;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that the page is reloading even though it should not? I assume you are using jQuery? Try to write your form submit handler like this:

```
frm.submit(function (e) {
    if (e) {e.preventDefault()};
    //...
});
```

As far as I remember, returning false only works if you attach handlers the old-fashioned way, in jQuery you have to explicitly suppress the default action of the event triggered by the form submit.